# How to migrate from Oracle 11g Single Instance residing on a Azure Linux VM to Oracle 19c RAC?

Tags: oracle-11g-r2, migration, oracle-19c, rac

What are the different ways to migrate from Oracle 11g Single Instance residing on a Azure Linux VM  to Oracle 19c RAC on Azure VMs?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.